# Karma coverage preprocessor not parsing CoffeeScript properly

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, karma-runner

My code is:

```
  $scope.$watch(->
    userService.getUser()
  , ->
    user = userService.getUser()
    $scope.authRoles = user.authRoles
  )
```

which is pretty innocuous. But when I run my test, I get:

```
ERROR [preprocessor.coverage]: Syntax error on line 19, column 6: unexpected ',' (\u002C)
16 :
17 :       $scope.$watch(->
18 :         userService.getUser()
19 :       , ->
^^ :~~~~~~^
20 :         user = userService.getUser()
21 :         $scope.authRoles = user.authRoles
22 :       )
```

My `karma.conf.coffee` looks like:

```
module.exports = (config) ->
  config.set
    basePath: '../../'

    files: [
      'dist/assets/vendor.js'
      'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js'
      'public/scripts/**/*.coffee'
      'test/webapp/unit/**/*.coffee'
    ]

    preprocessors:
      'public/scripts/**/*.coffee': ['coverage']
      'test/webapp/unit/**/*.coffee': ['coffee']

    singleRun: true

    frameworks: ['jasmine']

    browsers: ['PhantomJS']

    reporters: ['story', 'coverage']

    coverageReporter:
      type: 'html'
      dir: 'test/webapp/coverage/'
```

Any help? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way code coverage is done in coffeescript leaves a lot to be desired. It uses specific compiler (CoffeeScriptRedux) which is still not completed. Try to play with spacing (how about one more level of indent?) or extract this functions and put their names here. You have not much choice.